# Why is it not possible to deploy a smart contract from the client side?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I spent 2 hours doing research on how to deploy a smart contract from the client side on mobile. I tried searching on Google, checking blogs, youtube videos, but could not find an answer.

I went into the Solana mobile discord and asked "How I would deploy a smart contract from mobile" and a developer from the Solana Mobile team told me it was not possible. I could only interact with  the functions on the contract after it was deployed, but deploying it onto the network from mobile could not be done.

I don't think it's because the team hasn't implemented the functionality yet, because their Android SDK is a few years old.

In Ethereum using the Web3j library, the user can deploy the compiled byte code of the contract onto the Ethereum network.

So why is deploying a contract from the mobile device not possible on Solana?

Answer (score 0):

That echoes [`solana-mobile/solana-mobile-stack-sdk` issue 9](https://github.com/solana-mobile/solana-mobile-stack-sdk/issues/9) which asked (Apr. 2023):

> Are the Solana Saga phone and Solana Mobile Stack intended to be used only with the Solana network, or are there plans to support other ecosystems in the future that would like to integrate with the Solana Saga phone and build apps for it?
> A mobile phone as a hardware wallet and a decentralized app store would be a massive win for the whole crypto ecosystem.

But, from [`sdlaver`](https://github.com/sdlaver):

> We started with Solana, because we believe it is the best blockchain for mobile (speed, cost, and scalability). We do want to add support for other chains into the core SMS technologies (e.g. Seed Vault, Mobile Wallet Adapter), but we haven't announced any roadmap for such support at this time.

This could be because of resource constraints: Mobile devices often have limited processing power and memory. Deploying a smart contract can be a resource-intensive task, especially if the contract is complex.

But you would need  also to consider security risks: Mobile devices are generally considered less secure than server environments.
Not to mention network instability: If the connection is lost during the deployment process, this could lead to a range of issues including financial loss.

So it is possible the constraints and risks associated with deploying a new contract make it less suitable for execution from a mobile device.

Comment: The same could be said for all EVM compatible chains, not secure, network instability, etc, etc. But all EVM compatible chains can deploy directly from device. It doesnt make sense to me why they don't build that functionality

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE Sure, I meant that in the specific context of that particular project, to illustrate why it is not in their immediate roadmap.